# error when i am try to using in foregin key, foregin key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, create-table

when I am try to create a foreign key I am geting a error and I am not sure why its happening.

I will be happy if you can help my to fix and understand why this error happen.
thank you a lot.

[image]

Comment: Line 4: I think you accidentally named your table customers_id, instead of customers

Comment: @GMB got it right, just change the datatype of the foreign key to be `int` instead of `varchar`

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key column must have the same datatype as the column it refers to in the source table.

You have defined column `custmer_id` as `int` in the `customers` table, so you need to define `customer_id` as `int` as well in the `sales` table rather than `varchar(255)`.

Reference: [MySQL conditions and restrictions on foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

(1) The column type should be the same as mentioned by GMB

(2) In your foreign key statement, you are referring to table `customers`, but your first create table statement creates the table `customers_id`. So the foreign key statement should be:

```
foreign key(customer_id) references customers_id(customer_id) on delete cascade
```